# Permute the last column only using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have tried

```
import numpy as np
import paandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('Trans_ZS_Control_64')
df = df1.apply(np.random.permutation)
```

This permuted the entire data but i want to permute the value of last column only upto 100 times.
How do I proceed for this.

Input Data

```
0.051424  0.535067  0.453645  0.161857 -0.017189 -0.001850  0.481861  0.711553  0.083747  0.583215  ...  0.541249  0.048360  0.370659  0.890987  0.723995 -0.014502  1.295998  0.150719  0.885673     1
-0.067129  0.673519  0.212407  0.195590 -0.034868 -0.231418  0.480255  0.643735 -0.054970  0.511684  ...  0.524751  0.206757  0.578314  0.614924  0.230632 -0.074980  0.747007  0.047382  1.413796    1
-0.994564 -0.881392 -1.150127 -0.589125 -0.663275 -0.955622 -1.088923 -1.210452 -0.922861 -0.689851  ... -0.442188 -1.294110 -0.934985 -1.085506 -0.808874 -0.779111 -1.032484 -1.026208 -0.248476    1
-0.856323 -0.619472 -1.113073 -0.691285 -0.515566 -1.080643 -0.513487 -0.912825 -1.010245 -0.870335  ... -0.941149 -1.012917 -1.647812 -0.654150 -0.735166 -0.984510 -0.949168 -1.052115 -0.052492    1
..       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
-0.145871  0.832727 -0.003379  0.327546  1.409891  0.840316  0.700613  0.184477  0.962488  0.200397  ... -0.337530  0.988197  0.751663  0.480126  0.663302 -0.522189  0.512744 -0.063515  1.125415    0
0.972923  0.857971 -0.195672  0.190443  1.652155  0.763571  0.604728  0.115846  0.942269  0.453387  ... -0.522834  0.985770  0.570573  0.438632  0.737030 -0.445704  0.387023  0.031686  1.266407     0
0.281427  1.060266  0.172624  0.258344  1.544505  0.859777  0.689876  0.439106  0.955198  0.335523  ... -0.442724  0.929343  0.707809  0.290670  0.688595 -0.438848  0.762695 -0.105879  0.944989     0
0.096601  1.112720  0.105861 -0.133927  1.526764  0.773759  0.661673 -0.007070  0.884725  0.478899  ... -0.404426  0.966646  0.994733  0.418965  0.862612 -0.174580  0.407309 -0.010520  1.044876     0
-0.298780  1.036580  0.131270  0.019826  1.381928  0.879310  0.619529 -0.022691  0.982060 -0.039355  ... -0.702316  0.985320  0.457767  0.215949  0.752685 -0.405060  0.166226 -0.216972  1.021018    0
```

Expected output: randomly permute the last column

```
0.051424  0.535067  0.453645  0.161857 -0.017189 -0.001850  0.481861  0.711553  0.083747  0.583215  ...  0.541249  0.048360  0.370659  0.890987  0.723995 -0.014502  1.295998  0.150719  0.885673     0
-0.067129  0.673519  0.212407  0.195590 -0.034868 -0.231418  0.480255  0.643735 -0.054970  0.511684  ...  0.524751  0.206757  0.578314  0.614924  0.230632 -0.074980  0.747007  0.047382  1.413796    0
-0.994564 -0.881392 -1.150127 -0.589125 -0.663275 -0.955622 -1.088923 -1.210452 -0.922861 -0.689851  ... -0.442188 -1.294110 -0.934985 -1.085506 -0.808874 -0.779111 -1.032484 -1.026208 -0.248476    1
-0.856323 -0.619472 -1.113073 -0.691285 -0.515566 -1.080643 -0.513487 -0.912825 -1.010245 -0.870335  ... -0.941149 -1.012917 -1.647812 -0.654150 -0.735166 -0.984510 -0.949168 -1.052115 -0.052492    1
..       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
-0.145871  0.832727 -0.003379  0.327546  1.409891  0.840316  0.700613  0.184477  0.962488  0.200397  ... -0.337530  0.988197  0.751663  0.480126  0.663302 -0.522189  0.512744 -0.063515  1.125415    0
0.972923  0.857971 -0.195672  0.190443  1.652155  0.763571  0.604728  0.115846  0.942269  0.453387  ... -0.522834  0.985770  0.570573  0.438632  0.737030 -0.445704  0.387023  0.031686  1.266407     1
0.281427  1.060266  0.172624  0.258344  1.544505  0.859777  0.689876  0.439106  0.955198  0.335523  ... -0.442724  0.929343  0.707809  0.290670  0.688595 -0.438848  0.762695 -0.105879  0.944989     0
0.096601  1.112720  0.105861 -0.133927  1.526764  0.773759  0.661673 -0.007070  0.884725  0.478899  ... -0.404426  0.966646  0.994733  0.418965  0.862612 -0.174580  0.407309 -0.010520  1.044876     0
-0.298780  1.036580  0.131270  0.019826  1.381928  0.879310  0.619529 -0.022691  0.982060 -0.039355  ... -0.702316  0.985320  0.457767  0.215949  0.752685 -0.405060  0.166226 -0.216972  1.021018    1
```

Comment: what do you mean with upto 100 time? Only permute 100 random values and the rest of should stay the same? Only permute within the first? 100 elements?

Comment: want to suffle the last column 100 times

Comment: What's the reason for calling `np.permutation` a 100 times? Or rather, why do you want to shuffle 100 times and only return the last result?

Comment: @Josmoor98, I just needed 100 random permuted file for nulll hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sure if this is what you meant, but you could do it like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

v = np.arange(0,10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': v, 'c2': v, 'c3': v})
df
```

this would create the following df:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9
```

to permute the last column you could run this:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.c3 = np.random.permutation(df1.c3)
df1
```

resulting in:

```
   c1  c2  c3
0   0   0   5
1   1   1   9
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   6
4   4   4   0
5   5   5   4
6   6   6   8
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   1
9   9   9   3
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Just create a dataframe from your last column and permutate that. It seems like permutating individual columns with `apply` doesn't work the way you expect it to.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Trans_ZS_Control_64')

column_to_change = pd.DataFrame(df['last_column_name'])
for i in range(100):
    column_to_change = column_to_change.apply(np.random.permutation)

df['last_column_name'] = column_to_change
```